# Java Logger Producing Multiple of the Same Log to Console

Tags: java, scala, logging

I have the following code, we are not using `System.out.println` statements but have to use a logger to print out to console.

Here is example code (Java):

```
public void printColumnStats() {
        java.util.logging.Logger log = java.util.logging.Logger
                .getLogger("ProfileStatusClass");
        log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
        handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        log.addHandler(handler);
        // This will print the current Column Profiling stats
        log.fine("FieldName : " + this.datasetFieldName);
        log.fine("Field index : " + this.fieldIndex);
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00000000");
        if (this.fieldType.equalsIgnoreCase("number")) {
            log.fine("Field Null Count : " + this.datasetFieldNullCount);
            log.fine("Field Valid/Obs Count : " + this.datasetFieldObsCount);
            log.fine("Field Min : " + (0l + this.datasetFieldMin));
...
```

I have the following call for it (sorry this part is in Scala, but should be straight forward:

```
 for (e <- tResults) {
        e._2.printColumnStats()
        println("++........................................................++")
      }
```

What I am getting tons of repeats before the next set of stats pulls up even though there is just one of each type for the loop:

```
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
Field Null Count : 0.0
```

Comment: why did you instantiate your log instance in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a new ConsoleHandler on every call to 'printColumnStats'. You only want to install one handler.  If you are going to use code to setup the logger then **move the setup code out of the printColumnStats function** and into a static block.

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ProfileStatusClass");
static {
    log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
    handler.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    log.addHandler(handler);
}
```

By default, the JVM will install a ConsoleHandler on the root logger too.  Your logger should setUserParentHandlers to false so you don't publish to that handler too.

Comment: Added this log.setUseParentHandlers(false); and still no change.

Comment: What did you do with regard to installing the ConsoleHandler multiple times?